# Not able to Consume wcf service POST method in Portable class library for xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin

I am consuming wcf webservices(POST method) in Portable class library in visual studio for xamarin android.App is getting crash in POST method.Below is my code

IN PCL

Class1.cs

```
namespace XamarinServiceCall
{
    public sealed class Class1 : IRestService
    {

        public async Task<string> GetData(UserModel model)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var result = await client.PostAsync("http://xamarin-rest-service/LoginService/ValidateLogin", content);
                return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

IRestService.cs

```
namespace XamarinServiceCall
{
    public interface IRestService
    {
        Task<string> GetData(UserModel model);
    }
}
```

UserModel.cs

```
public class UserModel
    {

        public string loginFrom { get; set; }

        public string domainName { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        //I get response of below parameters
        public int DomainType { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
      }
```

In Xamarin Android APp

### MainActivity.cs

```
namespace ServiceSample
{
    [Activity(Label = "LayoutSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
            protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            XamarinServiceCall.Class1 serviceClass = new XamarinServiceCall.Class1();
           var model = new XamarinServiceCall.UserModel { domainName = "domainname" ,userName = "username" , password = "password" ,loginFrom = "App" };

            var result = await serviceClass.GetData(model);
            button.Text = "get call says: " + result;

        }
    }
}
```

Postman Response:

[image]

When i debug i get this response in result variable.

[image]

When i point to postAsync Function it shows me Expression is not valid

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? Do you get an exception in debugger? Please add the output of the debugger - error message, stack etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to perform any significant work, like calling your web service, inside OnCreate function of MainActivity.

And of course, you should not make it async  and make asynchronous calls inside it. Please check Xamarin's examples.

Generally, in OnCreate you can make some initialization and then call LoadApplication for your Application class (which you can define in PCL project).

Comment: It will be very helpfull if you could show me some example regarding consuming wcf service in xamarin android

Comment: Before you consume a wcf service, you should get working application. As for now, you don't load your application properly. I'll try to find some example later on.

Comment: Its working  Service,Actually to stackOverflow i had posted wrong URL purposefully.above i have posted postman response and response from debug.Please check

Comment: @dafodil,your current problem is not the service, but the application as a whole. Try to comment your call to service and check whether your app is still crashed. If it is not, uncomment the call and post the call stack from the debugger from the moment of crashing. But I think that it will crash even without call to service. Then try to read 'getting started' examples from Xamarin website, and get example of working Xamarin.Andriid application. After that add your service consuming.

Comment: I have corrected it,Now app is not crashing.First i checked by removing service method and then by adding service call method,App doesnot crash.But i get no response.

Comment: In this case close the current thread, open a new one, post the updated code and the exact explanation. You can post a link to that question here in comment, if you want us to continue the debugging

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067531/not-able-to-get-response-body-from-wcf-service-in-pcl-for-xamarin i have posted new question