# Not able to get response body from wcf service in PCL for xamarin

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, xamarin

I am trying to consume a wcf service in PCL for  xamarin android in visual studio,on calling service i want to get json response body.But here i wont get any response body except 200 status.Can Please anybody help me.Any suggestion and help are appreciated.Below is code used.

Class1.cs

```
 namespace XamarinServiceCall
{
    public sealed class Class1 : IRestService
    {

        public async Task<string> GetData(UserModel model)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("domainName",model.domainName ),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userName", model.userName),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", model.password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("loginFrom", model.loginFrom),
        });
var result = await client.PostAsync("http://xamarin-rest-service/LoginService/ValidateLogin", content);

            return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

MAinActivity.cs

```
namespace ServiceSample
{
    [Activity(Label = "LayoutSample", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
            protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            XamarinServiceCall.Class1 serviceClass = new XamarinServiceCall.Class1();
           var model = new XamarinServiceCall.UserModel { domainName = "domainname" ,userName = "username" , password = "password" ,loginFrom = "App" };

            var result = await serviceClass.GetData(model);
            button.Text = "get call says: " + result;

        }
    }
}
```

Below figure shows the data i get on debug for result variable

[image]

Below is what i need to send(URL) and get response json body

http://xamarin-rest-service/LoginService/ValidateLogin?domainName =domainname&userName = username&password =password&loginFrom =App

Response postman:

"DomainType":2, "FirstName":dallia, "Status":2, "UserId":3

Any help or suggestion are appreciated.Please help me i am very new to c# and xamarin.

Comment: I created a Postman request using the parameter values in your example, and the API call does not return what you show as Postman response. It returns 200 with empty body (Content-Length = 0). Seems like the parameter values are causing this behavior.

Comment: @Mark Larter Please refer this link i have posted same question ,I have edited it with more image for more clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057544/not-able-to-consume-wcf-service-post-method-in-portable-class-library-for-xamari